Bluetooth Stereo module to Mono amp
I'd like to add a Bluetooth signal to a mono amp, actually feeding in the audio will be pretty easy on the volume control.
As the Bluetooth module is Stereo though, and the amp Mono... I need to know how to combine both channels. A lot of the music I listen to has different audio on both channels or music travels from right to left or left to right... I know I'll lose the effect but I don't want to lose hits of the music. I've heard just soldering the channels together is bad, and creates muddy audio, and I have heard mixed messages on putting resistors inline for each channel before combining them into the single signal, some say it fixes the muddiness others says it just lessons the volume.
I have looked you can't buy a mono bluetooth module. Here is the module I intend to buy for completeness.
https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/235442932238?mkcid=16&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-127632-2357-0&ssspo=vyxjezxuqjw&sssrc=2047675&ssuid=dXnXG4QxQUG&widget_ver=artemis&media=COPY
Thanks in advance.


And I have heard mixed messages on putting resistors inline for each channel before combining them into the single signal, some say it fixes the muddiness

It's what needs to be done. You want a linear combination, an amplifier is a high-impedance load, your bluetooth receiver drives that with potentially a lot lower impedance, and thus, adding up with resistors in-line and ideally one from the combination point to ground is the way to go.

others says it just lessons the volume.

Others seem to have a different kind of amplifier (with a low input impedance), or no idea.

Here is the module I intend to buy

You get the service and quality you pay for. If things sound muddy, it's not going to be the fault of your resistors…

Thank you, confirmation is what I needed. I didn't however know about the resistor from the combination point to ground so will look this up more as I want to make it sound as good as I can.
I know the eBay module is cheap, but I've used them Stereo to Stereo in the past and the audio isn't that bad. They're also unfortunately all the same, I have a few just chip on board, and others chip on board with headphone amps. I don't know which is best to use, but I don't suppose amplifying the audio before the the amp is a wise idea. I'm also very limited on space so the smaller it is make it easy

thing is that these least-cost modules typically only support really old Bluetooth profiles / audio codecs for audio, and these are really noticably more muddy than modern codecs.
